# Why Refill of Gel Pen contains some transparent type liquid?

Tags: material-science

See This Image you will get full clarity What I was asking:
[image]

I also read the wikipedia page of Gel Pen, no where mentioned about this Transparent Thing What I am asking about.

Comment: **viscosity** plays important role in Gel Pen refill, That is why I posted [**here**](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really physics, but since you asked the clear fluid is called the [ink follower](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gel%20pen%20ink%20follower).

The gel is a suspension of pigment particles in an aqueous solution of a polymer. The gel has to have just the right properties - it has to be thick enough to suspend the pigment particles but thin enough to flow onto the ball and then the paper. As it happens many polymer solutions are shear thinning, and since suspending the pigment is low shear while flowing onto the ball is high shear a single polymer can meet both requirements.

However using a shear thinning polymer does mean that in high stress situations, e.g. dropping the pen onto the floor, the gel could shear thin and flow out of the end of the tube and create a mess. Adding a plug of ink follower prevents this. The ink follower does not have to flow onto the ball and paper and it doesn't have to suspend oxide particles, so it can be chosen solely for its ability to resist sudden shocks like dropping the pen.

Ink followers tend to be low volatility oils of various types thickened with a solid such as silica or clay. Being non-polar means they don't mix with the gel, and it also prevents evaporation of the gel.